# jquery - rating plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to display current rate and allowing re-rating on the same inputs, but it doesn't work. I could display current rate but disable re-rating or vice versa. I am using that plugin: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-API .
Here is what I got:

Here I got version with properly display current rate:

```
$('.voting-star').rating().rating('select', '3');//

        $('.voting-star').rating({
            callback: function(value, link){
                alert(value);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/false/address/xxx?rate=' + value + '&photo_id=123425',
                });
            }
        });
```

And here is version with allowed re-rating (but when site is ready I can see that 'alerts' shows many times - and the same number AJAX request is started:

```
    $('.voting-star').rating({
        callback: function(value, link){
            alert(value);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/false/address/xxx?rate=' + value + '&photo_id=234234',
            });
        }
    });

    $('.voting-star').rating().rating('select', '%{$current_img->getLoggedUserRate()}%');
```

Comment: What plugin are you using for rating? A link would be helpful :)

Comment: Sure, that's one http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `callback` function is being called multiple times when you call `select` through the API. You could do something like this instead:

```
/* Check the appropriate rating (replace with server side code if necessary): */
$(".voting-star[value='3']").attr("checked", true);

/* Initialize the rating plugin: */
$('.voting-star').rating({
    callback: function(value, link) {
        alert(value);
    }
});
```

Here's a working example (without AJAX): http://jsfiddle.net/ErmRS/1/

Answer (score 1):

I advise you [Raty](http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/)

```
$('#star').raty({
    half: true,
    start: /* your current average */
}).click(function() {
    $.ajax /* etc */
});
```

Comment: Thx for advice, but unfortunetly I must use that, I am working on some older webapp, change is not possible (old jquery, etc...)